# find natural numbers $a$ and $b$ with a special property

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory

Find all natural numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and 
$$\dfrac{a}{b}=b.a$$
 Also $b.a$  is a decimal number.

For example $\dfrac{5}{2}=2.5$

Comment: Where did you find this problem? Or is it out of curiosity?

Comment: It is a problem of math Olympiad exam in my country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this equation?: $$\frac{a}{b} = b + \frac{a}{10^k}$$

We might as well clear denominators and see what happens:

$$10^ka = 10^kb^2 + ab$$

Manipulating this a bit:

$$a = \frac{10^k b^2}{10^k - b} =  \frac{10^{3k}}{10^k-b} - 10^{2k} - 10^k b$$

Because $(a,b)=1$, we can draw strong conclusions about the cancellation in $\frac{10^{3k}}{10^k-b}$, namely that $10^k-b = 2^{3k}$.  A lesser power of $2$ would lead to $2\mid (a,b)$, and a factor of $5$ would lead to $5\mid (a,b)$.  Note that $10^k-b=5^{3k}$ is too large.  This gives us $a=5^{3k}-10^{2k}-10^k$.

Now to bound $k$ and wrap up the problem.  We have $a<10^k$, so $5^{3k}-10^{2k}-10^k < 10^k$.  Rearranging, $5^{3k} < 2\cdot 10^k + 10^{2k} < 2\cdot 10^{2k}$, so $5^{3k} < 2\cdot 10^{2k} \implies 1.25^k < 2$, which holds only for $k=1,2,3$.

One more observation: The equation $10^ka = (10^kb + a)b$, and the facts that $(a,b) = 1$ and $5\not\mid b$, implies that $b$ must be a power of $2$.

For $k=2$, we have $b=10^2-2^6 = 36$, which is not a power of $2$.

For $k=3$, we have $b=10^3-2^9=488$, which is not a power of $2$.

For $k=1$, we have already seen the solution $b=10-2^3 = 2$, $a = 5^3-10^2 - 2\cdot 10 = 5$, which we now see is the only solution.

---

Please point out any possible bugs; the method is quite awkward and I would definitely approach this differently now that I understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is equivalent to saying $\frac{a}{b} = b+ \frac{a}{10}$. That being said, we can do the following algebra: $$\frac{a}{b} = b+ \frac{a}{10} \\ \implies \frac{a}{b}-\frac{a}{10} = b \\ \implies \frac{10a-ab}{10b}=b \\ \implies 10a-ab = 10b^2 \\ \implies a(10-b) = 10b^2 \\ \implies a = \frac{10b^2}{10-b}$$ You can verify that the formula works by plugging in $b=2$. You will get $a=5$, as you stated in your question already. Now, we can observe a few things about the quantity $$\frac{10b^2}{10-b}$$ Clearly $0 < b<10$. If $b\geq 10$ we would be dividing by zero or force the quantity to becomes negative. There is still a bit of guess and check involved, but you know the only numerical candidates to check are $b = 1,2, \cdots , 9$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{a}{b}=b.a \Rightarrow \frac{a}{b}=b+\frac{a}{10^k} \Rightarrow 10^ka=10^kb^2 +ab$$
where $k$ is the number of digits of $a$.

From here it follows that $b |10^k a$ and hence, as a,b are relatively prime. $b|10^k$.

Also $a|10^k b^2$ and hence $a |10^k$. Moreover, $10^k|ab$.

The equation $a|10^k, b^10^k$ and $10^k|ab$ with $gcd(a,b)=1$ is very easy to solve in general. The only solutions are $(10^k,1), (2^k, 5^k), (5^k,2^k), (1, 20^k)$, which are obtain by covering the cases $2|a$ or $2|b$ and $5|a$ or $5|b$. You can simply check which of them satisfy the original equation.

Note also that $10^{k-1} \leq a< 10^k$ restricts the possible $k$ to very few in each case.